# SQL Correlation with Tables that aren't Directly Related

Tags: sql, join, union

I need to perform a lookup using SQL to see if these 3 columns match my id. I tried JOIN, but the columns don't have any join point. No clear correlation. I also tried UNION, but they have different number of columns and different column data types. Basically I need to dip into 1 table to get a value. Use that value to dip into a 2nd table to get an additional value. Then use both of those values along with a hardcoded value to dip into a 3rd table to retrieve a unique value. Then use that unique value to dip into a 4th table to get the results that match the unique value. Here is the query that I have currently:

```
SELECT * FROM DEF_TABLE
WHERE DEF_ID IN (
SELECT DEF_ID FROM DESCRIPTION_TABLE 
    WHERE MY_TYPE = 'EQP'
    AND COL_TYPE = a
    AND COL_NAME = b
        IN (SELECT COL_TYPE as a, COL_NAME as b FROM TYPE_TABLE WHERE COL_TYPE IN
           (SELECT COL_TYPE FROM EQP_TABLE WHERE ID = 9000)));
```

---

EDIT: I found that running COL_TYPE and COL_NAME checks as seperate calls it works, but very slowly. Is there another way?

```
SELECT * FROM DEF_TABLE
WHERE DEF_ID IN (
SELECT DEF_ID FROM DESCRIPTION_TABLE 
    WHERE MY_TYPE = 'EQP'
    AND COL_TYPE IN (SELECT COL_TYPE FROM TYPE_TABLE WHERE COL_TYPE IN
                    (SELECT COL_TYPE FROM EQP_TABLE WHERE ID = 9000))
    AND COL_NAME IN (SELECT COL_NAME FROM TYPE_TABLE WHERE COL_TYPE IN
                    (SELECT COL_TYPE FROM EQP_TABLE WHERE ID = 9000)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like what you're trying to do is

```
SELECT * FROM DEF_TABLE
WHERE DEF_ID IN (
    SELECT DT.DEF_ID 
    FROM DESCRIPTION_TABLE DT 
        JOIN TYPE_TABLE TT 
        ON   DT.COL_TYPE = TT.COL_TYPE
        AND  DT.COL_NAME = TT.COL_NAME
        JOIN EQP_TABLE ET
        ON   DT.COL_TYPE = ET.COL_TYPE
    WHERE DT.MY_TYPE = 'EQP'
      AND ET.ID = 9000 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm. I didn't consider trying to do a join inside the query like that.